# How do I parse a string representing a nested list into an actual list?

Tags: python, parsing, string, exec, nested-lists

Say I have a string representing some nested lists and I want to convert it into the real thing. I could do this, I think:

```
exec "myList = ['foo', ['cat', ['ant', 'bee'], 'dog'], 'bar', 'baz']"
```

But in an environment where users might be supplying the string to execute this could/would be a bad idea. Does anybody have any ideas for a tidy parser that would accomplish the same thing?

Comment: +1 for knowing this kind of thing has risks and asking about it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
>>> import ast
>>> mylist = ast.literal_eval("['foo', ['cat', ['ant', 'bee'], 'dog'], 'bar', 'baz']")
>>> mylist
['foo', ['cat', ['ant', 'bee'], 'dog'], 'bar', 'baz']
```

[ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or
>   a string containing a Python
>   expression. The string or node
>   provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures:
>   strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating
>   strings containing Python expressions
>   from untrusted sources without the
>   need to parse the values oneself.

Comment: +1 import ast making the rounds, good stuff!

Comment: Cool. Just last week I used eval() for the first time, but ast.literal_eval is what I really wanted. Note, I used eval to parse a config file value, so it's trusted data, but still...